# Firestore DocumentReference type to object

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-flow

As you can see in the picture, the documents in the person collection refer to the statistics collection.
[image: Firestore collections]

I can pull this data like this

PersonRepository

```
override fun getPersonsFromFirestore(): Flow<Response<List<Person>>> = callbackFlow {
    val snapshotListener =
        personsCollection.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
            val response = if (snapshot != null) {

                val personList = snapshot.toObjects(Person::class.java)
                Response.Success(personList)

            } else {
                throw Error(e?.message ?: e.toString())
            }
            trySend(response).isSuccess
        }
    awaitClose {
        snapshotListener.remove()
    }
}
```

Model

```
data class Person(
    val id: Int=0,
    val name: String="",
    val surname: String="",
    val image_url: String="",
    val biography: String="",
    val team: String="",
    val statistics: DocumentReference? = null,
    var personStatistics: PersonStatistics? = null
)
```

How can I convert Document Reference to object here?

I tried this first

```
 override fun getPersonsFromFirestore(): Flow<Response<List<Person>>> = callbackFlow {
    val snapshotListener =
        personsCollection.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
            val response = if (snapshot != null) {
                val personList = mutableStateListOf<Person>()

                snapshot.onEach {
                    val person = it.toObject(Person::class.java)

                        person.statistics!!.get().addOnSuccessListener {
                            val personStatistics = it.toObject(PersonStatistics::class.java)
                            person.personStatistics = personStatistics
                        }

                    personList.add(person)
                }
                //val personList = snapshot.toObjects(Person::class.java)
                Response.Success(personList)
            } else {
                throw Error(e?.message ?: e.toString())
            }

            trySend(response).isSuccess
        }
    awaitClose {
        snapshotListener.remove()
    }
}
```

but in this approach Person Statistics comes first as null. It is added later. How can I bring them all at once? Or is there another better way?

Comment: I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8), with the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp) will help. As mentioned there, try to use the first approach and use `toObjects()`.

Comment: @Tislam, Did you find any soultion for this case ? , I'm facing the same issue for document listener

Comment: @Mohammad Al-Hussein Yes I found. I wrote the method I used below.

Answer (score 2):

Okey, This is how I solved it,

```
override fun getPersonsFromFirestore(): Flow<Response<List<Person>>> = callbackFlow {
    val snapshotListener =
        personsCollection.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
            val response = if (snapshot != null) {
                val personList = mutableStateListOf<Person>()

                snapshot.onEach {

                    val person = it.toObject(Person::class.java)
                    val statistics = it.data["statistics"] as DocumentReference

                    statistics.addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
                        if (value!=null){
                            person.personStatistics = value.toObject(PersonStatistics::class.java)
                            personList.add(person)
                        }else{
                            throw Error(error?.message ?: error.toString())
                        }
                    }
                }
                Response.Success(personList)
            } else {
                throw Error(e?.message ?: e.toString())
            }

            trySend(response).isSuccess
        }
    awaitClose {
        snapshotListener.remove()
    }
}
```